# Disable handlers from running

Tags: ansible

Is there any way to stop handlers from running ? I was trying to add tag and use "--skip-tags" to it but it does not work.

I could add next role variable `reload_service: true` and use it but I've already started using tags and they work great to just re-run part of role.

Handlers are usually used to restart services and I want to run this role without starting service without changing role variables just to cover next case.

I'm using `ansible 2.1.2.0`

Test case:

`mkdir -p test/role/handlers test/role/tasks
cd test
echo -ne '---\n  - command: "echo Test"\n    notify: restart\n' > role/tasks/main.yml
echo -ne '---\n- name: restart\n  command: "echo Handler"\n  tags: [handlers]\n' > role/handlers/main.yml
echo -ne '---\n- hosts: localhost\n  gather_facts: false\n  roles:\n    - role\n' > play.yml
ansible-playbook play.yml --skip-tags handlers`

Comment: This is incomprehensible: "*I want to run this role without starting service without changing role just to cover next case.*"

Comment: @techraf I meant that I do not want to change variables, ideally I should not have any conditional variables like `rsyslog_add_service: true` but I would just use tags which are easier to control.

Comment: But you can't use tags. What is the question? And you have not explained what that sentence meant - I see no connection.

Comment: @techraf so this is big inconsistency and therefore bug. Ansible docs mentions that handlers are just like tasks but will be executed if any other task does notify. It does not crash when I add tags to it but it does not use them either.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: you already answered - there is no option to use tags to control handlers run.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is currently no variable within Ansible which lets you test which tags have been specified at runtime.

As you have discovered, handlers run regardless of assigned tags. The documentation does not make it clear whether this is a bug or intended behaviour.

Some options are:

- Add another variable to the task and use this since handlers can still be conditional on the `when:` clause.
- Have the handler include another file with the action and a tag assigned. The file will always be included, but the tag will make the action conditional.
- Have a tagged action in the task which then sets a local variable for the handler. This conversion in task would allow tags still be used at runtime.

Comment: yep these are only valid options, however I'm dissapointed how divided ansible is, I'm just switching to salt.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example of how you could use a variable to skip a handler:

```
$ cat test.yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - copy:
      content: "{{ ansible_date_time.epoch }}" # This will always trigger the handler.
      dest: /tmp/debug
    notify:
      - debug

  handlers:
  - name: debug
    debug:
      msg: Hello from the debug handler!
    when:
    - skip_handlers | default("false") == "false"
```

Normal use would look like this:

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yaml
```

And to skip the handlers:

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yaml -e skip_handlers=true
```

Answer (score 2):

Since [v2.5.0](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.5.0/changelogs/CHANGELOG-v2.5.rst#minor-changes), Ansible has an [ansible_skip_tags](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#term-ansible_skip_tags) special variable that stores the tags passed with `--skip-tags`. Since `when` clauses work with handlers, this is how I'm working around the issue:

```yaml
- name: Restart nfs-server
  ansible.builtin.service:
      name: nfs-server
      state: restarted
  when: "'tag_you_want_to_skip' not in ansible_skip_tags" # This is the important line
```

Now `--skip-tags tag_you_want_to_skip` will work as expected and skip the handler